# If Statement with Expression inside .map() within React Return()

Tags: reactjs

I believe the problem I'm having is because my map function is within the return method within react. Is this not possible to do?

What needs to happen is I'm mapping through survey data.  I need to average the columns for each.  So I'm adding column1 + column2 + column3, and then need to divide by the number of responses given.  I can't just divide by 3, because some people left one of the responses blank.  So I came up with the code below, but it's giving me this error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

```
render() {
        
        return (
            <Jumbotron className="text-dark">
                <Div>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Table striped bordered>
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Client</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Score: Consulting</th>
                                    <th>Score: Talent</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {
                                    this.state.surveyData.map((client) => {
                                    let consultingScoreDiv = 0;
                                    const consultingScore = client.value1 + client.value2 + client.value3;
                                    if (client.value1 !== ""){ consultingScoreDiv++ };
                                    if (client.value2 !== ""){ consultingScoreDiv++ };
                                    if (client.value3 !== ""){ consultingScoreDiv++ };

                                            <tr key = { client.id } >
                                                <td>{client.orgName}</td>
                                                <td>{client.name}</td>
                                                <td>{consultingScore/consultingScoreDiv}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }                                        
                                        
                                    )
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </Table>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Div>
            </Jumbotron>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had few issue:

- You are missing the a `return` in your `map`.
- You check for empty string, instead of `undefined` or `typeof`
- you calculated the total even if there was no value there.
- You did not check division by 0.

Here's how it should look like:

```
{this.state.surveyData.map((client) => {
  let consultingScoreDiv = 0;
  let consultingScore = 0;
  if (typeof client.value1 === "number") {
    consultingScoreDiv++;
    consultingScore += client.value1;
  }
  if (typeof client.value2 === "number") {
    consultingScoreDiv++;
    consultingScore += client.value2;
  }
  if (typeof client.value3 === "number") {
    consultingScoreDiv++;
    consultingScore += client.value3;
  }

  return (
    <tr key={client.id}>
      <td>{client.orgName}</td>
      <td>{client.name}</td>
      <td>
        {consultingScoreDiv > 0
          ? consultingScore / consultingScoreDiv
          : 0}
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

Comment: It still gives me the Failed to Compile Error 3 times for each If statement.  Says "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".  It doesn't like the way the if statements are done.  I wasn't sure if I'm missing something with my syntax, or if React doesn't allow you to use them this way.